# Android Long Press Spinner View

Tags: android, contextmenu, spinner

I want to be able to long press items in the spinner view and have a contextMenu appear. I tried this code:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.catagorySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
registerForContextMenu(spinner);
```

but as you can guess this added a context menu to the actual Spinner and not to the contents inside. Does anyone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
        spinner.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

                view.showContextMenu();
                return true;

            }
        });
```

Comment: that only works on the Spinner button itself not its contents

Comment: Documentation says spinner does not support item click listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can register for each item inside the adapter's `getView()` method.

```
View getView(View convertView, ... ) {
   ....
   // inflate view or reuse.
   ....
   getContext().registerForContextMenu(convertView);
   ....
   return convertView;
}
```