# Spinner setOnItemLongClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-contextmenu

I need to add the ability to edit the spinner items using a context menu or a dialog that should appear when user long press an item

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462934/android-long-press-spinner-view) I have see that someone has tried to use

```
spinner.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

                view.showContextMenu();
                return true;

            }
        });
```

but such method doesn't work.

I populate the Spinner with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_item_layout, itemList); spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have see in another question that simply has been suggested to avoid to try to implement context menu for the `Spinner` but I don't have much space so I cannot use `ListView` without ugly results, and this action is needed only for rare situation,  so a Context menu or something similar seems the only valid choice.

How could I implement a context menu for the `Spinner`or extend the Android Spinner to support long click on items inside Spinner?

Comment: try to crosscheck your "spinner id"/ if you have nested view then disable focus on that layout to get event on spinner

Comment: I have a Spinner that shows an Array of String(no custom Spinner  implemenbtation), I haven't understood what do you mean. Could you give me more details?

Comment: Can you please add your code to debug..we can not help you until we can see your implementation...

Comment: the code of what? I populate the Spinner with `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_spinner_item_layout, itemList);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: context menu are different from long click

Comment: I know mina, but I could use also the long click to show a dialog that can help me to meet my problem

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a custom spinner class by extending spinner,

```
public class CCSpinner extends Spinner {
    public CCSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, mode);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int mode) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, mode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

Use the above spinner in your xml view.

2) Define an interface to handle clicks,

```
 public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemLongClicked(View view);
        void onItemClicked(View view);
    }
```

3) In your spinner adapter class do these stuffs in getView and getDropDownView

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ususal stuffs
        convertView.setTag(R.string.click_tag, position);
        convertView.setClickable(false);
        convertView.setLongClickable(false);



        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ususal stuffs
        convertView.setTag(R.string.click_tag, position);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onItemClicked(v);
                }
            }
        });


        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onItemLongClicked(v);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

4) While instantiating the adapter, pass the ClcikListener interface we created.

5) and in the implementing class do the following,

```
@Override
    public void onItemLongClicked(final View view) {
        mPSpinner.onDetachedFromWindow();
        final int pos = (int) view.getTag(R.string.click);
        mPSpinner.setSelection(pos);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(final View view) {
        mPSpinner.onDetachedFromWindow();
        int pos = (int) view.getTag(R.string.click);
        mPSpinner.setSelection(pos);
    }
```